# Top padding with cursive fonts on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts

When I try to use a cursive font on a mobile website, it seems to sit too high, eating in to any top padding I set on the element. In order for it to look normal on mobile, I have to add around twice the normal top padding. [Here](http://davidstrout.me/testing/cursive.htm) is an example. This happens on Chrome on Android and Safari on iPhone. Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround?

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with the way the font is constructed where it eats up space. Instead of top padding you could add line-height to get it to where you want to

Comment: @Keith I decided to give that a try and came up with this: http://davidstrout.me/testing/lineheight.htm - same problem.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? My Chrome on Android looks like my desktop browser.

Comment: @Huelfe added a screenshot. This is Chrome 53.0.2785.124 on Android 6.0.1.